# Error Msg: Pure Abstract Class wrapped in a Namespace in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, abstract-class

Need help with implementing a **pure abstract class via inheritance**, **using namespace** to wrap all my classes to avoid conflict with others.

I have been able to build and run the code successfully if I remove namespace wrapper from my abstract class and all classes that inherit from my pure abstract class.

It seems like Visual Studio 2010 compiler is complaining that despite all classes are in the same namespace, the abstract class's pure abstract method is not implemented.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
//IBaseClass.h

//forward declaration
class ConcreteClass;

//namespace MyCustomNamespace
//{
    class IBaseClass
    {
    public:
        virtual ~IBaseClass() { /*virtual destructor*/ }
    //Behaviours...
        virtual bool Method001( const ConcreteClass &cc ) = 0;
        //virtual bool Method002(/*some input*/) = 0;
    };
//} /*NAMESPACE*/

//-----------------------------------------
//ParentClass.h

//namespace MyCustomNamespace
    //{
    class ParentClass : virtual public IBaseClass
    {
    private:
        int a;

    public:
        virtual ~ParentClass() { /*virtual destructor*/ }

        //getter-setter implemented in ParentClass.cpp file...
        void setA(const int aa); 
        const int getA() const; 
    };
//} /*NAMESPACE*/


//-----------------------------------------
//ConcreteClass.h

//namespace MyCustomNamespace
//{
    class ConcreteClass: public ParentClass 
    {
    private:
        int b;

    public:
        virtual ~ConcreteClass() { /*virtual destructor*/ }

        //getter-setter...
        void setB(const int bb);             
        const int getB() const;

        bool Method001( const ConcreteClass &cc ); //re-declaring IBase abstract method...
    };
//} /*NAMESPACE*/


//-----------------------------------------
//ConcreteClass.cpp


//namespace MyCustomNamespace
//{
    void ConcreteClass::setB(const int bb) { this->b = bb; } 
    const int ConcreteClass::getB() const { return this->b; }

    bool ConcreteClass::Method001( const ConcreteClass &cc )
    {
        //implementation code goes here...
        return false;
    }
//} /*NAMESPACE*/
```

Comment: This actually works fine for me. Can you post the error?

Comment: The code I have posted here works, if you un-comment the namespace portion in each class .h and .ccp files, then it will throw error mgs that my ConcreteClass is an abstract method. It seems like the compiler can't figure out that I have implemented the pure abstract method in my ConcreteClass, unless I remove the namespace from all classes that use the IBase class

Comment: With the namespaces uncommented, it [still works](http://ideone.com/cpv7x). Could you post the exact code that causes the error (and the exact error message)?

Comment: I have edited the code to show what I am doing exactly. I have a pure virtual method that takes an input of my 'ConcreteClass'. The Pure Abstract class does have a forward reference to my ConcreteClass. I also inherit from my Parent class, but forward declaration should resolve cyclic loop. I re-declare the pure abstract methods in my ConcreteClass, but for some reason the compiler is having a problem recognizing it. It is giving me a _C2259: MyCustomNamespace::ConcreteClass : cannot instantiate abstract class_ error msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your forward class has been declared in another namespace (specifically, the global namespace). Thus, the virtual to override is a different symbol with a different parameter type.

As written, the compiler matches `ConcreteClass` to the forward declaration it sees in the global namespace when declared in the base:

```
virtual bool Method001( const ConcreteClass &cc ) = 0;
```

When you declare `Method001` in `ConcreteClass`:

```
virtual bool Method001( const ConcreteClass &cc );
```

the compiler matches `cc` to `MyCustomNamespace::ConcreteClass` because that is a more accurate match.

To resolve the issue, just place your forward declaration in the proper namespace:

```
namespace MyCustomNamespace {
  class ConcreteClass;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just had to put the forward declaration inside the namespace. Picked up something new today, I thought all #includes and declarations were suppose to be declared outside of namespace....live and learn.

Comment: @badboy11 you're welcome. it's also possible to `#include` within a namespace -- if you want the effect of "copy and paste this file here, within this namespace". it's more common to see an `#include` in a class declaration.